# SiriKit INSendPaymentIntent could not trigger the application on iOS 17

Tags: ios, sirikit, ios17

My iphone application has been using the INSendPaymentIntent since 2017 (iOS 11).

It works perfectly so far but it can not trigger the application after the user gives the amount and the person whom to send money with iOS 17.

I could not see any update with the intent on [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insendpaymentintent) too. Has anyone run into the same problem and/or any idea?